# OneHotEncoder categories with strings

Tags: string, scikit-learn, categories, one-hot-encoding

I am having a dataset in the following shape:

| type_of_bicycle_lane | month | other variables |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'on the street' | 1 | ... |
| 'fully seperated' | 4 | ... |
| 'fully seperated' | 8 | ... |
| 'fully seperated' | 1 | ... |
| 'other_1' | 12 | ... |
| 'other_2' | 8 | ... |

I am trying to pass this trough a scikit learn pipeline, specifically through a OneHotEncoder to use it for various ML models. However, for the `type_of_bicycle_lane` I only want to create the OneHotEncoding for the `categories = ['on the street', 'fully seperated']`.

Thus, I wrote the following code:

```
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("bicycle_lane", OneHotEncoder(categories = ['on the street', 'fully seperated']), ["type_of_bicycle_lane"]),
    ])
```

However, I keep receiving the Error: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).

I consolidated the documentation and I am meant to the parameter categories should be a list of array-like where "categories[i] holds the categories expected in the ith column. The passed categories should not mix strings and numeric values within a single feature, and should be sorted in case of numeric values." [Link to documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

I have used this OneHotEncoder before (such as

```
("month", OneHotEncoder(categories = [range(1,13)]), ["month"])
```

which worked perfectly fine.

What might I be doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categories should be a list of array. Additionnaly you should indicate handle_unknown='ignore' or 'infrequent_if_exist' to avoid an error message.

```
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("bicycle_lane", OneHotEncoder(categories = [['on the street', 'fully seperated']], handle_unknown='ignore'), ["type_of_bicycle_lane"]),
    ])
```